# GCP terraform metadata_startup_script yields the following error: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Creating a `rhel-7-v20230411` GCP instance using terraform, but the `metadata_startup_script` is failing:

```
  metadata_startup_script = <<EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "Downloading and installing Application"
    echo "Echoing user"
    whoami
    echo "Echoing pwd"
    pwd
  EOF
```

The error being reported in `Serial port 1 (console)` is:

```
Apr 25 15:07:03 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: Starting startup scripts (version 20230403.00).
Apr 25 15:07:03 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: Found startup-script in metadata.
Apr 25 15:07:03 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: startup-script: /bin/bash: /tmp/metadata-scripts1524519383/startup-script: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Apr 25 15:07:03 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: startup-script exit status 126
Apr 25 15:07:03 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: Finished running startup scripts
```

If I create a little `temp.sh` file in my instance (and make it executable) it executes without error:

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
pwd
```

output:

```
nollen
/home/nollen
```

I've read the documentation and seen examples, but I am unable to make `metadata_startup_script` work.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `^M` is a carriage return, so see if you can save the terraform file **without** `\r\n` line endings

Comment: @glennjackman, the issue did not fundamentally change:

`Apr 25 16:39:47 cockroachdb-instance-0 google_metadata_script_runner: startup-script: /bin/bash: #015: No such file or directory`

Comment: try `dos2unix myFailingScript`. (-; ... Good luck.

Comment: Did an edit to the above. Refresh your screen for uptodate comment.

Comment: @Ron, since there's no bash, does `/bin/sh` exist on the remote host? bash is _common_ but it's not everywhere.

Comment: The error message is often caused by the wrong file format (unix vs dos) which uses different line endings (CR vs CRLF). Edit your post with details. 1) which editor did you use? 2) which operating system are you editing files on? If you understand the `vim` editor, use the command `:set ff`. If should report `unix`.  The error indicates the format is `dos`. Use `:set ff=unix` to change the file format. [more einformation](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acux)

Comment: JohnHanley, glennjackman, shellter Thank you for the help -- you were correct the problem was line endings.  The problem was so obvious that I dismissed it and instead decided it had to be a Google problem.